# Example of CarouselPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Is there any documentation and example of using `CarouselPage` with Prism for Xamarin Forms?

The issue I have is with navigation.

I'm trying to navigate to add a page to the carousel

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("PrismCarouselPage1/PrismContentPage1")
```

But it's not adding the page to the carousel, instead it's just navigating to `PrismContentPage1` like it's a top page.

I'm using latest released version of Prism for XF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, nor will there be documentation or official examples with CarouselPage. Please see the talk Jason Smith gave at Evolve where he specifically says that you should not use CarouselPage and you use use CarouselView instead.

https://youtu.be/RZvdql3Ev0E

Comment: There's one here https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Sandbox/Xamarin/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/App.cs edited 12 days ago.

Comment: I am confused. I know what you're saying about `CarouselPage` but Xamarin Forms still has it. The reason they don't recommend it is because `CarouselView` is a view which can be put inside other pages. But it's not like `CarouselPage` is bad

Comment: Also, I see support for `CarouselPage` in Prism: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Behaviors/PageBehaviorFactory.cs

Comment: Listen to Jason... CarouselPage is bad... the only reason it's still in Forms is because CarouselView hasn't been pulled into Forms and is still an extra package. It's only loosely supported... and what support Brian and I have done for it is more for legacy.. you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Also taking `ViewA/ViewB` only adds ViewB to ViewA if ViewA is a MasterDetailPage in which it sets the Detail of ViewA to ViewB... and a NavigationPage... What you see in the Sandbox selects an existing Page in a CarouselPage... and only in the latest CI packages

Comment: For now, I have to use `CarouselPage`. I'm refactoring an app to Prism. Is there a way to navigate to `PrismContentPage1` without having `PrismContentPage1` added as a child already? I mean have `PrismContentPage1` added by Prism

Comment: You would need to explicitly add the Children... the Navigation Service will not navigate from one child to another within the CarouselPage just like it will not do that in a TabbedPage. Using the latest CI package you can as shown in the Sandbox select the active Page

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to add children. Should I override `INavigationService`? Not sure how to do that..

Comment: Actually, I was wondering if there's any example with `CarouselView`

Comment: @DonBox As for how to use CarouselView please see Google... as for how to add children you would do that on your CarouselView manually... there is no dynamic way to do that currently... you are welcome to create an [issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/new)

Comment: I was referring how to use CarouselView with Prism, when you want to navigate to next view within the carousel

Comment: Would overriding NavigationService be a good idea? I could check which page is current, if it's the one I know it has CarouselView, I could then set current page for CarouselView based on the given navigation key

Comment: It's a view inside a Page... What you're asking is the same as asking how you could use INavigationService to navigate inside of a StackLayout or a Grid... it's a fundamentally flawed question. Please do some research so you understand the context of what you're working with.

Comment: I don't agree. The idea of 'navigating' can mean anything. I saw your implementation of popups. Why isn't navigating by showing a popup "flawed" too? You're showing a popup

Comment: @DonBox Navigating with the context of INavigationService cannot "mean anything", you need to spend some time learning how Xamarin Forms works. The Popups Plugin is night and day different and is able to extend INavigationService because a PopupPage is a Page not a View...

Comment: When I said "mean anything" I was obviously referring that INavigationService can be extended.

Comment: I can't teach you Xamarin Forms on StackOverflow... spend some time learning.

Comment: No need to teach me Xamarin Forms. My question was specifically about navigating. You make it look like it's a general question. Please look to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/navigation/ Where does it says it's only about pages? It talks about views, not pages.

Comment: Wouldn't be much more practical and helpful if you could give an actual  suggestion instead? Telling me "your question is flawed, go learn Xamarin Forms" is not really helpful. If you want to be helpful, you could just say what's the actual problem, if you see any. Thanks

Comment: @DonBox I have already told you. You want to be right rather than take the guidance you’ve been given.

Comment: I don't want to be right, I was just looking for help to understand what options I have. You gave no guidance on the actual question regarding navigation within CarouselView. You just said "your question is flawed, go learn Xamarin Forms". That's not guidance. You didn't explain at all why is it flawed in any way.

Comment: Funny, even the documentation of Prism for Xamarin Forms says that "In Prism, the concept of navigating to a View or navigating to a ViewModel does not exist. Instead, you simply navigate to an experience, or a unique identifier, which represents the target view you wish to navigate to in your application"

Comment: So it really means navigating to "anything"